# Freeing an array of character pointers (string literals)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I'm trying to figure out how to free the memory for an array of character pointers (string literals), but I can't quite get the syntax. This is how I'm declaring and initializing the arrays.

```
char * words[] = { "THESE", "ARE", "SOME", "WORDS" };
```

I've tried doing this...

```
free(words);
```

And this...

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    free(words[i]);
}
```

But the first one causes some sort of invalid pointer error with glibc, and the second one causes a segmentation fault.

So what's the right way to free this memory?

Comment: This is a statically initialized array. You shouldn't be freeing it anyway.

Comment: don't `free` something you didn't `malloc`.

Comment: "what's the right way"? Do nothing. It's freed automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you did not allocate it (e.g `malloc`, `calloc`) then you shouldn't be deallocating it either (e.g `free`).

Documentation will in general be very clear and explicit if you need to free a pointer returned from a function, for example [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) would be such a case.

Comment: Ah, alright. I ask because I have some memory leaks in my program and it looked like those arrays had the right number of elements to be the culprit. Guess I get to have more fun with my vector and string libraries...

Comment: Try debugging with _valgrind_.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau: Don't program by random guessing. Learn the rules of the language and follow them.

Comment: This is true in Standard C.  In POSIX and compiler extensions, sometimes you find functions that return memory you must `free()` despite the fact that you didn't malloc it. For example, `strdup` and `getline`.